# Which service spams the console with [OK] Finished ServiceName Messages? And how to turn it off?

Tags: boot, systemd, log, plymouth

```
[OK] Reached target Late Shutdown Services  
[OK] Finished System Power Off  
[OK] Reached target System Power off
```

These messages are not affected by kernel boot parameters like `loglevel=3` or `rd.systemd.show_status=false` or  `rd.udev.log_level=3`

They also don't go away if i edit the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/plymouth-start.service` file and add `--no-boot-log` to plymouthd. The file `/var/log/boot.log` is still written and filled with those messages. So is the console behind plymouth splash.

So I'm absolutely in the dark.

where do those messages come from and how can i kill, reprogram and delete this service. I just want a real silent boot.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu release? When I correct remember it was bootlogd

Comment: thx.. 22.04 but there is no such service as bootlogd